# How can I change color of more than one div of the same id using addEventListener("click")?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Good day,

I have a CSS grid of 9 square divs, and I would like to add a click event for all of them so that their color changes from limegreen to black, and then changes back to limegreen when the mouse leaves. I am able to do so if I give each div a unique ID and use .addEventListener, but then the issue is I have to write a click event for each div. When I try to give each div the same ID and use .addEventListener, the click event only happens with the first div.

I have spent the past hour or two searching Stackoverflow, Google, forums, and other websites, along with tinkering with my code based on what I've found, but I can't find anything that has helped so far.

Here is my code, but I've only included the HTML/CSS for the first two divs, since the rest of the divs are like the 2nd div and don't respond to clicks:

```js
const dude = document.getElementById("dude");

dude.addEventListener("click", function(){
    dude.style.backgroundColor = "black";
});
dude.addEventListener("mouseleave", function(){
    dude.style.backgroundColor = "limegreen";
})
```

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  margin: 7rem;
  position: relative;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  column-gap: 2.5rem;
  row-gap: 2.5rem;
}

.box {
  background: limegreen;
  width: 10rem;
  height: 10rem;
  position: relative;
}

.box2 {
  background: limegreen;
  width: 10rem;
  aspect-ratio: 1/1;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
        <div class="box" id="dude"></div>
        <div class="box2" id="dude"></div>
    </div>
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Yes, it totally helps! Thank you! I was approaching everything from the wrong angle.

Answer (score 0):

In HTML, two or more elements cannot have the same ID.
In your HTML, add a common class to the div(s) inside of `.container`.

```html
<div class="container">
      <div class="box gridbox"></div>
      <div class="box2 gridbox"></div>
</div>
```

Now use this Javascript code:

```js
/**
  *  Use this because we're getting the elements with 
  *  their class, not id. This method returns an array
  *  of the elements with matching class.
  */
const dudes = document.getElementsByClassName("gridbox");

/** Loop over the whole array */
for(let dude of dudes){
    /** Add click event handler */
   dude.addEventListener("click", () => {
       dude.style.backgroundColor = "black";
   });
    /** Add mouseleave event handler */
   dude.addEventListener("mouseleave", () => {
       dude.style.backgroundColor = "limegreen";
   });
}
```

This should work fine.